# R ggparagraph will introduce random line breaks and not use full plot width

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I've been arranging a few plots via ggarrange and want to use one of the plots as a field to enter a description. However, no matter how I enter the text or how wide the plot ends up being, there are random line breaks where they needn't be.

```
# Summary paragraph creation
summaryText <- paste("\n\nGenotype for",
                     " rs", summaryRs,
                     " in ", summaryGene, " ",
                     "(trackno", trackno, ")\n\n",
                     "Fig. A – Bar chart with number of observations, \nFig. B – Jitter plot with linear regression, \nFig. C – Violin/Boxplot with means",sep="")
summaryPlot <- ggparagraph(text=summaryText, size=12, color="black")
```

[A wide variation of the arranged plot still leads to line breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYhj9.png)

I've tried varying the creation of `summaryText` and looked for formatting options for ggparagraph but to not avail. Even a much wider arranged plot (as seen) does not eliminate these line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the docs are a bit sparse, IMHO the issue is that `ggparagraph` is not meant to be used with manual line breaks. Instead the docs state that `ggparagraph`

> Splits a long text into multiple lines (by inserting line breaks) so that the output will fit within the current viewport.

Hence, your string is taken as one long string and `ggparagraph` will insert additional line breaks (not taking account of your manually added line breaks).

Instead, one option to achieve your desired result would be to use e.g. `gridtext::textbox_grob`. Note that instead of `\n` we have to use the HTMl tag `<br>` to add a line break when using `gridtext::textbox_grob`:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(gridtext)

summaryRs <- 10521432
summaryGene <- "MAOB"
trackno <- 12070397

summaryText <- paste0(
  "<br><br>Genotype for",
  " rs", summaryRs,
  " in ", summaryGene,
  "(trackno", trackno, ")<br>",
  "Fig. A – Bar chart with number of observations,<br>",
  "Fig. B – Jitter plot with linear regression,<br>",
  "Fig. C – Violin/Boxplot with means"
)
summaryPlot <- gridtext::textbox_grob(summaryText)

# Density plot
density.p <- ggdensity(iris,
  x = "Sepal.Length",
  fill = "Species", palette = "jco"
)

# Arrange the plots on the same page
ggarrange(summaryPlot, density.p,
  ncol = 1, nrow = 2,
  heights = c(.5, 1)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've since abandoned this format and went with a simple bottom annotation. But I will look into ```text_grob```s! They seemed a little unwieldy but probably ultimately more appropriate. Also: No matter if I added manual line breaks or not, it would seemingly randomly introduce them.